# Users' Table Authorizations Disappearing Randomly

Tags: sas, business-intelligence

I'm facing an issue where user table authorizations seem to be disappearing randomly, even though there have been no intentional changes made on my end. The setup involves configuring authorizations for each table based on user groups. Additionally, filters and direct parameters are applied for each group and their respective access types.

The problem arises from the fact that these direct parameters are seemingly wiped out at irregular intervals without any manual intervention. This issue is causing significant disruptions as it's blocking regular operations.

To give you more context, here's a simplified outline of the process:

1. Users are created and configured via SaaSnow portal which is stable.
2. Authorizations are added for tables, categorized by user groups.
3. Filters and direct parameters are meticulously assigned for each group and the specific type of access they require.
4. Periodically, and seemingly randomly, these direct parameters are inexplicably cleared, even though no changes are deliberately being made.

I've thoroughly reviewed configuration settings, but nothing stands out as the cause. We have contacted SAS Viya support and they have said that the issue is on our side.

Has anyone else encountered a similar situation with SAS Viya?

Comment: I'm surprised tech support wasn't more helpful.  I don't see a lot of SAS admin questions here. If you don't get a helpful answer, you might want to try posting this question to the admin community at communities.sas.com: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Administration-and-Deployment/bd-p/sas_admin

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, I have already posted the same question on the SaS community. I hope somebody will help on this.